# How does retain works in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, properties, retain

I have this code.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"stat"]) {
        currentKey = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"];
        currentValue = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
    }  
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    [currentValue appendFormat:string];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([currentKey isEqualToString:@"url"])
        self.urlToServerLog = currentValue;
}
```

And the header file

```
    @interface HDEAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate> {
@private
    NSWindow *window;
    NSString* scratchFolder;
    NSMutableString *urlToServerLog;
    NSString *currentKey;
    NSMutableString *currentValue;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *output;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *matchID;
@property (retain) NSString *scratchFolder;
@property (retain) NSMutableString *urlToServerLog;

-(IBAction) ParserButton:(id)sender;
-(NSFileWrapper*)unzip:(NSData*)zipData;

@end
```

The problem here is the object at urlToServerLog/currentValue gets removed.

I found a solution is to copy the object but my original solution still stands.
Why doesn't retain work in this case?

BTW: scratchFolder is also used with a autorelease object and it's working perfectly.(Using in the exact same way, return from NSString(autorelease) and assign to scratchFolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `-parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:`, you allocate a new string and autorelease it:

```
currentValue = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
```

This means that the this string will be released when the corresponding autorelease pool is drained. In general, if an object needs to be kept alive after a method has finished executing, you need to own it. In your case, do not autorelease it at this point (and remember to release it when you don’t need it any longer), or make `currentValue` a `retain` property and use `self.currentValue = …` instead.

Another point to consider: you probably want to make `urlToServerLog` a `copy` property instead of a `retain` one because `currentValue`, being a mutable string, will be changed while the XML parser is being executed. If you’re using `retain`, your `urlToServerLog` property will also change since it points to the same mutable string. By changing the property to `copy`, you effectively make a copy of `currentValue` — any further changes to `currentValue` won’t affect that property.

Comment: I don't get it, I not that good just starting.
currentValue is a ivar it's not a property at all.
When we assign currentValue to self.urlToServerLog, don't that call retain on currentValue so the count is added by one.
Won't it?

Comment: @Jonathan I’ve edited my answer and included a further paragraph. You probably want `copy` instead of `retain`.

Comment: @Bavarious, got some more questions. Great help by the way. Thanks.
currentValue won't change because it's being allocate again as you seen above. So it location will change and the old one will stay to same.
Second is I can't use copy, because it a mutable object. Again preferred work around other than using mutableCopy(preferred on the property itself).
Third is, is it using (if it's a property) "test = [alloc]; test = nil; test = [alloc]" and "test = [alloc]; test = [alloc]" the same? Will the second example call "release"?

Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan But `currentValue` is allocated (and soon after deallocated! read the first paragraphs in my answer) only inside that `if`, right? Well, I guess it depends on the XML schema.

Comment: @Jonathan As for your last question: Yes, they’re the same **but** you’re leaking an object since you haven’t released the first one prior to allocating the second one.

Comment: @Jonathan As for mutable copy properties, Objective-C doesn’t support them. I’d personally use a custom setter that sends `-mutableCopy` instead of `-copy` if there’s actual need for it to be mutable.

Answer (score 1):

`currentValue` is being released when `didStartElement:` finishes. I assume `currentValue` is a class variable? What value do you see for `urlToServerLog` after you assign `currentValue` to it?

Comment: currentValue is released when didStartElement ended.
But won't assigning currentValue to urlToServerLog add a retain count?

Comment: currentValue is already gone at that point. There is no retain count because there is no object.

Comment: But if I do "self.urlToServerLog = [currentValue mutableCopy];". It's still valid. So the object shouldn't be gone right?

Comment: That would seem to make some sense... try it. :-)